# using _s versions of functions like _tcsset , _tcscpy etc while migrating from VS2003 to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am migrating a MFC application from VS2003 to VS2010. The are thousands of calls to function like _tcsset, _tcscpy, _tcsupr etc. Upon building after migrating, C4996 warnings come suggesting to use _s versions of these functions. I have been asked to not use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and remove all warnings by changing these calls and use _s versions. There are thousands of calls and in many cases the TCHAR* is coming from external as an argument. I cannot tell how big target buffer is . So, what are my best options.?
e.g.

```
TCHAR* fnc(TCHAR* tsrc, TCHAR* tdest)
{
  _tcsset(tsrc,0);
  _tcscpy(tdest,tsrc);
  return(tdest);
}
```

If i need to change these calls to _tcscpy_s. What should i do? Is it not better to use non _s versions in such case?

Comment: Fix the calls. If there were no length limits provided the code was already pretty-broken from a security standpoint (the code you posted would be decent evidence of that). A search and replace will have the raw pointer usage puking at compile-time. You're going to have to bite the bullet and fix the calls one way or another, including possibly providing templates for your own functions (`fnc` in this case) to assist. Bottom line: if the guy that signs your check said what your question instructed, gotta do it (or stop using C string functions by stopping using C strings; also lots of work).

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply.   but if I leave these calls as _tcscpy in case of external TCHAR*, would it not be better. Beause the code is working well and fine in VS2003. Or if chnage the call to :  '_tcscpy_s(tdest,_tcslen(tsrc)+1,tsrc);'   would it not just do the job by a thin margin.

Comment: "Working" is in the eye of the person authoring buffer overflow attacks.

Comment: *"What should i do?"* - You should probably read [Security Features in the CRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) first to understand, why the functions you were asked to replace are dangerous, and how the security enhanced functions address those vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been told to change all the functions to use `_s`, you have to get on and do it.  Your example function will have to change to:

```
TCHAR* fnc(TCHAR* tsrc, size_t src_els, TCHAR* tdest, size_t dst_els)
{
  _tcsset_s(tsrc, src_els, 0);
  _tcscpy(tdest, dst_els, tsrc);
  return(tdest);
}
```

... Then you will have to change the calls to it to match, and probably have to pass the lengths into those functions, lather, rinse, repeat.

The alternative is to switch to `std::tstring` (where `tstring` is a typedef for either `string` or `wstring` as appropriate).  This will be just as much work, but will result in a cleaner interface that is *much* harder to cause buffer overflows in.

As a side issue, do you still build your code in both wide and narrow versions?  If not, I would take this opportunity to rip out TCHAR altogether, and just use `wchar_t`.

If you don't use `std::string/wstring`, you should probably use the SAL annotations, so the function would be declared as:

```
TCHAR* fnc(
     __inout_ecount(src_els) TCHAR* tsrc, size_t src_els, 
     __out_ecount(dst_els) TCHAR* tdest,  size_t dst_els)
```

That way the tool sets can (to at least a certain extent) check that you are passing in the right values.

You probably also want to write templated versions of the functions that count the elements for you:

```
 template <size_t s, size_t d>
 TCHAR *fnc( TCHAR (&tsrc)[s], TCHAR (&tdest)[d] )
 {
     return fnc( tsrc, s, tdest, d );
 }
```